# How to identify why there are unwanted type in the generated swagger documentation.How to prevent it?

Tags: java, swagger

For our project we use swagger.version->1.5.16 and swagger-maven-plugin (3.1.5) to generate swagger documentation for our public REST API (written in java + swagger annotations)

The problem is that in the generated documentation there are types listed that does nothing to do with the public API - no API method use these as params, neither as return types.

Why this might happen and how can we prevent it? (Any debug logs while generating the swagger doc to help identify the reason?)

Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
public class Vehicle {

     public StrangeObject strangeMethod() {
          return null;
     }

     public class StrangeObject<T> {}
}
```

and the bike:

```
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;

@Path("/bikes")
@Api
public class Bike extends Vehicle {
     @DELETE
     @Path("/book")
     @Produces({ "application/json" })
     @ApiOperation(nickname = "bookBike",
                value = "Book a Bike",
                code = 200,
                response = Boolean.class)
     @ApiResponses(
                value = {
                          @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
                          @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found")
                })
     public Boolean handleBook(
                @PathParam("id") @ApiParam(value = "The ID of the bike.") String id) {
          return Boolean.TRUE;
     }
}
```

The StrangeObject appears in the Definitions swagger document and this is what I want to fix.
**NOTE**: Assume that I don't have access to Vehicle, it comes from external library.

Comment: What types? We need *more*

Comment: Types from the dependent libraries used in the project. For example, we extend classed from other projects and we have swagger definitions in such classes.

Comment: Are you using SpringFox or some other framework? Can you post some code and an example of the actual results and expected results?

Comment: @Helen I updated the question with code example.